# Can I get the status of a previous stage build in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job, that uses the pipeline mechanics. It has several steps. For understanding let's assume I have 3 stages. the first 2 run in parallel, the 3rd after them. Now depending on the result of the last build of stage 3 I want to do different thing.
If stage 3 was previously successful, I want the result from stage 1, otherwise take stage 2 result. 
Is this possible to check? I don't get how to retrieve the last result of a stage, only did a similiar thing for last state of a job.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "pipeline mechanics"? Which plugin are you using? workflow? MultiJob? or just triggering downstream jobs?

Comment: Hard to tell for me, since I have no access to plugin settings. When I create a new Job it says: "Pipeline
   Orchestrates long-running activities that can span multiple build slaves. Suitable for building pipelines (formerly known as workflows) and/or organizing complex activities that do not easily fit in free-style job type." ... I thought this was now integrated into Jenkins w/o plugin.

Comment: So you do appear to be using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin - the page it links to, https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/, may have links to help you with your issue.

Comment: @Matthias - I have pretty same issue. So far I did not manage to access Stage Result directly, but good entry point is `currentBuild.rawBuild` global variable, which is available throughout your pipeline. It returns you a `Run` object, described [here](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html). You may then call smth like `currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()` and dig into jenkins API in order to somehow retrieve Stage results. Please also make sure, that an access to `rawBuild` is allowed in your Jenkins groovy sandbox.

Comment: Since those are stages, not jobs - you should be able just to set a boolean flags that's available to all stages. From your description, it seems to be just one Jenkinsfile/Pipeline with some stages in it. Could you please post some code?

Comment: Another workaround would be to use [this plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/tree/master/rest-api)

Comment: @BlazejChecinski Wow, actually it was as easy as to use some global variables that are available everywhere...now I feel dumb not trying it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write output from only succesfull job, no need to check then
2. I've not heard stage status, you've to break your stages into separate jobs and then use 'job status'